# TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() <= datetime.datetime()

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have fields in my django app `live_from` and `live_to` these fields are non required. When this fields are empty i get an error in my metod:

Fields:

```
live_from = models.DateTimeField('live from', blank=True, null=True)

live_to = models.DateTimeField('live to', blank=True, null=True)
```

here is my method:

```
def is_live(self):
    return (self.live_from <= timezone.now()) and (self.live_to >= timezone.now())
```

Bug: `TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() <= datetime.datetime()`

Comment: Looks less like a coding error and more like a design error. If those fields are empty, what is `is_live` supposed to do?

Comment: So either `live_from` or `live_to` is None, because you allow nulls. The exception hows that `life_from` is `None` here, but the same applies to `live_to`. What should happen if either one of those is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you trying to compare [NonType](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None) with current time, you should return False when the value is empty at first,for instance:

```
def is_live(self):
    if self.live_from is None or self.live_to is None :
        return False
    return (self.live_from <= timezone.now()) and (self.live_to >= timezone.now())
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good definition, given your model.

```
def is_live(self):
    # first, check the inexpensive precondition, before comparing date fields
    return ((None not in [self.live_from, self.live_to]) and 
            self.live_from <= timezone.now() and self.live_to >= timezone.now())
```